# D3 how to show my dataset in text or using legend

Tags: javascript, d3.js, text, legend

I want to display a legend or text or my data at my chart. 
I can display my chart but I don't know how to display the "lab" and "labno" value like a text. I dont know where should I put my legend.
I want to display it inside my chart function.

I want to display something like this

> x is 30 
>   y is True 
>   z is True

Here is my code

```
 var data =
 [
   {algo:"a ", accuracy: 50, lab:"x ", labno: 30  },
   {algo:"b", accuracy: 96.29, lab:"y", labno:"True" },
   {algo:"c", accuracy: 95, lab:"z", labno: "True" }
   ];


function drawBarcharts(data) {
var margin = {top:10, right:10, bottom:90, left:50};
var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
   var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
   var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .03)
   var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0])
   var xScale2 = d3.scale.linear();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(xScale)
   .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left");


var svgContainer = d3.select("#chartID").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width+margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height",height+margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g").attr("class", "container")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+ margin.left +","+ margin.top +")");

xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.algo; }));
yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.accuracy })]);



var xAxis_g = svgContainer.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height) + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text");


    var yAxis_g = svgContainer.append("g")

    .append("text")
    .text("abc");

  svgContainer.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.algo); })
  .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.accuracy); })

  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - yScale(d.accuracy); })

  svgContainer.selectAll(".text")     
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class","label")
    .attr("x", (function(d) { return xScale(d.algo) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2 ; }      ))
    .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.accuracy) +10; })

    .attr("dy", ".75em")
   .text(function(d) { return d.accuracy; })

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Test</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    </script>
 <style>
 body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: center;
}

text{
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
}

.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path{
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}

.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis .tick line {
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.axisHorizontal path{
  fill: none;
}

.axisHorizontal line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axisHorizontal .tick line {
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
  fill-opacity: .9;
}


 </style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="chartID"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var data =
 [
   {algo:"a ", accuracy: 50, lab:"x ", labno: 30  },
   {algo:"b", accuracy: 96.29, lab:"y", labno:"True" },
   {algo:"c", accuracy: 95, lab:"z", labno: "True" }
   ];


var drawBarcharts = function() {


   
var margin = {top:10, right:10, bottom:90, left:50};
var width = 450 - margin.left - margin.right;
   var height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
   var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .03)
   var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0])
   var xScale2 = d3.scale.linear();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
   .scale(xScale)
   .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left");


var svgContainer = d3.select("#chartID").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width+margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height",height+margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g").attr("class", "container")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+ margin.left +","+ margin.top +")");

xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.algo; }));
yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.accuracy })]);



var xAxis_g = svgContainer.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height) + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text");


    //var yAxis_g = svgContainer.append("g")
    //.append("text")
    //.text("abc");

  svgContainer.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.algo); })
  .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
  
  .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.accuracy); })

  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - yScale(d.accuracy); })

  svgContainer.selectAll(".text")     
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class","label")
    .attr("x", (function(d) { return xScale(d.algo) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2 ; }      ))
    .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.accuracy) +10; })

    .attr("dy", ".75em")
   .text(function(d) { return d.labno; })

   
   var legend = svgContainer.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });


legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(function(d) { return d.lab + ' is ' + d.labno; });
 
}(data);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I know why the downvote? Did I get the question wrong? I was assuming pepo wanted to display a legend with contents he hasn't used in the chart.